# Android Custom Dialog implies a Force Close

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-dialog

I'm calling a dialog function on my code, but everytime I test it it makes a force close...
Here's my code:

```
   public void onLongPressFinished(MotionEvent arg0,
                ManagedOverlay arg1, GeoPoint arg2, ManagedOverlayItem item) {


            if (item!= null) // if the user longpresses a marker, it will pop up the route dialog
            {

                RouteDialog dialog = new RouteDialog();
                dialog.showCustomDialog();


            }
```

and the class I use to implement the dialog:

```
package com.BuStopTracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class RouteDialog extends Activity{



        public void showCustomDialog(){

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.routetodialog);//loads layout from xml file
            dialog.setTitle("Título do custom dialog");

            final Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_ok);
            final Button cancelar = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_cancel);
            final EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.inputText);

            ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //OK button action

                }
            });

            cancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

        dialog.show();

        }



}
```

I know that my "LongPress detector" function is working, because I tested it with a toast, and it worked fine...

So, can someone help me? I'm pretty sure my fault is in the way I call the dialog, I just can't see why or where...

Thanks.

PS: As requested, here's the logcat:

```
11-13 20:13:54.789: D/dalvikvm(406): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1153K, 54% free 3159K/6727K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 4ms+4ms
11-13 20:13:55.109: D/dalvikvm(406): GC_CONCURRENT freed 616K, 51% free 3363K/6727K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 5ms+7ms
11-13 20:13:55.369: D/dalvikvm(406): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 721K, 54% free 3116K/6727K, external 2121K/2137K, paused 52ms
11-13 20:13:55.829: I/MapActivity(406): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
11-13 20:13:55.829: E/MapActivity(406): Couldn't get connection factory client
11-13 20:13:55.979: D/dalvikvm(406): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 215K, 56% free 3020K/6727K, external 2440K/2692K, paused 77ms
11-13 20:14:17.679: D/AndroidRuntime(406): Shutting down VM
11-13 20:14:17.679: W/dalvikvm(406): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3536)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:141)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:123)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at com.BuStopTracker.RouteDialog.showCustomDialog(RouteDialog.java:23)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at com.BuStopTracker.BusTrackerBetaActivity$7.onLongPressFinished(BusTrackerBetaActivity.java:278)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at de.android1.overlaymanager.ManagedOverlayGestureDetector.invokeLongPressFinished(ManagedOverlayGestureDetector.java:76)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at de.android1.overlaymanager.ManagedOverlay.draw(ManagedOverlay.java:79)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at com.google.android.maps.Overlay.draw(Overlay.java:179)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:42)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:530)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-13 20:14:17.719: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 20:14:20.059: I/Process(406): Sending signal. PID: 406 SIG: 9
```

Comment: If you are getting a force close please post the logcat stack trace with the exception messages that occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not extend `Activity` in your RouteDialog. Pass a Context into `showCustomDialog` or make a contructor taking it and store it in your class.

To fix is easy change this, in RouteDialog:

```
public class RouteDialog {
        public void showCustomDialog(Context context){
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            /* leave rest as is */
```

And then change your code to show the dialog to:

```
RouteDialog dialog = new RouteDialog();
dialog.showCustomDialog(this);
```

Comment: I tried it, but in 
RouteDialog dialog = new RouteDialog();
dialog.showCustomDialog(this);
it just wont let me pass 'this' as a parameter, it gives me the following error:

The method showCustomDialog(Context) in the type RouteDialog is not applicable for the arguments (new ManagedOverlayGestureDetector.OnOverlayGestureListener(){}) BusTrackerBetaActivity.java /BusTrackerBeta/src/com/BuStopTracker line 278 Java Problem

Comment: Ah, you need to send in an context, so change it to 'BuStopTracker.this' instead.